# Time series where the datetime timezone is unknown

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have time series data for which I do not know the timezone of the timestamps, but I can assume that they all come from the same timezone. Should such data be typed using `as.POSIXct` or `as.POSIXlt`? And how can I specify that the timezone is unknown for these particular timestamps? For both `as.POSIXct` and `as.POSIXlt`, the timezone defaults to my system timezone, but I do not want that because I cannot assume that the timezone is my system's timezone.

Here is some example data:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(0, 1, 2),
  datetime = c("2014-02-17 12:04:42", "2014-02-18 09:29:51", "2014-02-19 17:29:10"),
  mood = c(4, 7, 6)
)

data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(data$datetime) # `as.POSIXlt` gives same output
data$datetime[1]
# output: "2014-02-17 12:04:42 CET"
```

Comment: Can you assume they are all the same timezone as one another?  Or are they from an assortment?

Comment: Yes, i can assume they are all from the same timezone

Comment: I don't think you can specify unknown timezones for datetimes in Base R. The clock package introduces a class of "naive" time which might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/r-lib/clock/
It might be simpler to just work with the UTC timezone which is geographically independent.

Comment: Possibly I am missing the point then, but if they are from the same time zone and the time zone is unknown then they are effectively just relational times/dates - the interval between them matters and the time zone is arbitrary.  Why is it an issue that it lists it as your local time zone?

Comment: Since I don't know the origin of the timestamped data, when printing the data if the output states that the the timezone is CET, then this implies that the data was collected in CET. You're right that the timezone is arbitrary, but it seems like a bad practice to make assumptions about the timezone.

Comment: In practice I think `as.POSIXct(x, tz = "UTC")` is going to be the easiest thing for you to use. If you truly don't know the timezone, then UTC is probably your best bet because most other timezones will have daylight saving time quirks that can come up as you begin to manipulate the date times.